# Different view of the main menu in Delphi and Lazarus

Tags: windows, delphi-7, lazarus

I use the WinAPI command with identical parameters but get different results in Delphi and Lazarus ("MyItem" will look different). I am using Windows 7, Lazarus 1.6.4 and Delphi 7.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModifyMenu(MainMenu1.Handle,
             MainMenu1.Items.Count-1,
             MF_BYPOSITION,
             MainMenu1.Items[MainMenu1.Items.Count-1].Command,
             '&MyItem' );
end;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't use Lazarus, but that menu looks like it is being owner-drawn. Perhaps your modification did something to affect how Lazarus draws the menu. Delphi uses a native Win32 menu and lets the OS default draw the top-level items normally (it does owner-draw the drop-down items, though).

Comment: I agree with you. Lazarus uses its own menu by default. But with my modification I disable it and force it to use native Win32 menu. The same as in Delphi. But they are different.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce a similar error, using Lazarus on Windows 10 (I can't try it in Windows 7 right now). As the visual style in W10 is different, the problem appears in a different way, but clearly related (client area background color used for the third item). I will try to trace it later today, but I suggest you contact the Lazarus people as this might be something they will need to address.

Comment: It might be a manifest that enables theming.  Maybe enable the xptheme unit under D7 ?

Comment: If this question is related to the previous one regarding right-aligning a menu item, you can do it in Lazarus by simply setting the `RightJustify` property `True` for the `MyItem` item. This is a property that exists in Lazarus, but not in Delphi. In fact, @Remy mentioned this in his answer to your previous question, but maybe you just overlooked it somehow. In short, if you use Lazarus, then set `RightJustify`, if you use Delphi-7,  use Remy's or mine solution from your previous question.